How to pass customactiondata with textbox value from dialog to Power shell script in InstallShield 2023
I am trying to create a basic MSI installer in Installshield 2023 which takes name and few other params from the dialog box and then from custom action calls one powershell script file passing the params to it. But the data is not getting passed to the powershell script. I can run the installer and it is creating the files under Program Files folder.
I am new to installshield. Any help appreciated. Thanks in Advance.



get-property -name CustomActionData

https://docs.revenera.com/installshield23helplib/helplibrary/CAPowerShell.htm
